# Query two tables with conditional order by in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

There are two example tables which look like

### tasks

```
 id | title  | user_id |
----|--------|---------|
 1  | test1  |    1    |
 2  | test2  |    1    |
 3  | test3  |    1    |
 4  | test4  |    1    |
 5  | test5  |    1    |
 6  | test6  |    1    |
 7  | test7  |    1    |
 8  | test8  |    1    |
 9  | test9  |    1    |
 10 | test10 |    2    |
```

### responses

```
 id  | task_id  |  status   |
-----|----------|-----------|
 1   |    2     |  pending  |
 2   |    2     |  pending  |
 3   |    2     |  accepted |
 4   |    2     |  accepted |
 5   |    2     |  declined |
 6   |    2     |  declined |
 7   |    3     |  pending  |
 8   |    4     |  declined |
 9   |    5     |  accepted |
 10  |    6     |  pending  |
 11  |    6     |  accepted |
 12  |    7     |  pending  |
 13  |    7     |  declined |
 11  |    8     |  accepted |
 12  |    8     |  declined |
```

- 'task_id' in responses is foreign key reference `tasks`.id

If I want to show a table which contains all tasks of user_id=1, the columns are:

- task id
- task title
- number of how many pending responses
- number of how many accepted responses
- number of how many declined responses
  additionally, each column must be sortable and task id should be distinct

In the example, the result should be:

```
 task_id | title | pending | accepted | declined 
---------|-------|---------|----------|----------
    1    | test1 |    0    |    0     |    0
    2    | test2 |    2    |    2     |    2
    3    | test3 |    1    |    0     |    0    
    4    | test4 |    0    |    0     |    1
    5    | test5 |    0    |    1     |    0
    6    | test6 |    1    |    1     |    0
    7    | test7 |    1    |    0     |    1
    8    | test8 |    0    |    1     |    0
    9    | test8 |    0    |    0     |    0
```

1. How to do the query once to get such a query result ? (If possible)
2. I tried to do the query like this:

```
    select `tasks`.*, count(`task_id`) as number
    from `tasks`
    left join `responses` on `responses`.`task_id`=`tasks`.`id`
    where `tasks`.`user_id`=1 AND (`responses`.`status`='pending' or `responses`.`task_id` is NULL)
    group by `tasks`.`id`
    order by `number`
    limit 0,50
```

However, this only works for 'pending' and no response. Meanwhile, there is error in this query even only for 'pending', those tasks with 0 pending response but have accepted or declined responses are missing through this query. How to correct it to get full tasks list?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*, sum(r.status = 'pending') as pending,
       sum(r.status = 'accepted') as accepted,
       sum(r.status = 'declined') as declined
from `tasks` t left join
     `responses` r
      on r.`task_id`= t.`id`
where t.`user_id` = 1 
group by t.`id`
order by accepted;
```